# Evaluating Expressions in Scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I am a bit new to scala and I have a program here that does everything I would like it to, except one thing I cannot seem to figure out. I Have expressions and I simplify the expression based on a few simple math rules.Then I prompt the user for bindings to variables and substitutes the variables with integers the user types in and then the expression is evaluated. That all works like I want it to. However I still want to simplify/evaluate the expression when I do not substitute a specific variable for an integer. I just simply evaluate the expression without asking the user for a value for x and I remove the statement for replacing x in my Environment for example. The problem is I get a scala.Match error when the eval method calls the env when it hits the x in my expression. To maybe make it clearer what I am trying to do is with the expression in my example.. Expression: (x + (x * (y - (z / 2)))) by only substituting the variables y and z with 2, the result I would like to see is (x + x). I would appreciate any advice/help possible! My program at this point looks like this:

```
var n1 = 0
var n2 = 0
var n3 = 0

type Environment = String => Int

lazy val exp: Tree = Sum(Var("x"), Times(Var("x"), Minus(Var("y"), Divide(Var("z"), Const(2)))))


lazy val env: Environment = {
  case "x" => n1          //take this line out to not bind x
  case "y" => n2
  case "z" => n3
}

abstract class Tree
case class Sum(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree {
  override def toString = "(" + l + " + " + r + ")"
}
case class Minus(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree {
  override def toString = "(" + l + " - " + r + ")"
}
case class Times(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree {
  override def toString = "(" + l + " * " + r + ")"
}
case class Divide(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree {
  override def toString = "(" + l + " / " + r + ")"
}
case class Var(n: String) extends Tree {
  override def toString = n
}
case class Const(v: Int) extends Tree {
  override def toString = v.toString
}

def simplify(t: Tree): Tree = t match {
  case Times(Const(1), r)     => simplify(r)
  case Times(l, Const(1))     => simplify(l)
  case Times(Const(0), r)     => Const(0)
  case Times(l, Const(0))     => Const(0)
  case Sum(Const(0), r)       => simplify(r)
  case Sum(l, Const(0))       => simplify(l)
  case Minus(l, Const(0))     => simplify(l)
  case Minus(l, r) if l == r  => Const(0)
  case Divide(Const(0), r)    => Const(0)
  case Divide(l, Const(1))    => simplify(l)
  case Divide(l, r) if l == r => Const(1)
  case Times(l, r)            => Times(simplify(l), simplify(r))
  case Sum(l, r)              => Sum(simplify(l), simplify(r))
  case Minus(l, r)            => Minus(simplify(l), simplify(r))
  case Divide(l, r)           => Divide(simplify(l), simplify(r))
  case _                      => t
}

def eval(t: Tree): Int = t match {
  case Sum(l, r)    => eval(l) + eval(r)
  case Minus(l, r)  => eval(l) - eval(r)
  case Times(l, r)  => eval(l) * eval(r)
  case Divide(l, r) => eval(l) / eval(r)
  case Var(n)       => env(n)
  case Const(v)     => v
}

println("Expression: " + exp)
println("Simplified: " + simplify(exp))
println("Enter the binding for x.")         //take this line out to not bind x
n1 = readInt()                              //take this line out to not bind x
println("Enter the binding for y.")
n2 = readInt()
println("Enter the binding for z.")
n3 = readInt()
println("Evaluation: " + eval(exp))
```

Comment: "The problem is I get a scala.Match error when the eval method calls the env when it hits the x in my expression. " Of course you do, since you're still passing in `"x"` but no longer providing a case for it. What  should `env` return for an unbound variable? I don't think this is a Scala issue, it's an issue in your design

Comment: I would like env to return the unbound variable which would be in this case "x" if I am not giving it an integer value

Comment: So return that from your env when no other case matches? Note env is currently a partial function -  you need to make it handle unknown/unbound variables (and so make it total). But I don't think that's enough - your eval assumes it can multiple, add, etc the results of the recursive calls to eval. Presently, leaves always return an integer (the bound value, or the constant value) - after your change, sometimes they return strings.... this is why I say it's a design issue - eval is not designed to return expressions, but to evaluate the value of one

Comment: Your design needs changing. You don't have anything that can partially evaluate an expression (although your simplify comes close - think about how to combine simplify and eval).

Comment: I guess this is what I am confused about, I need a case to handle unknown values, in which case I would return a string. But what confuses me is how can I return a string when env is required to return an Int?

Comment: You can extend simplify to do this. If you see `Sum(bound-var-or-const, bound-var-or-const)` you can actually perform the sum, and return a `Const(two-values-added-together)`. Enough hints, I'm not going to write the code for you :-P

Comment: Better is for you to write an extractor for (possibly) bound values - look up the doc for extractors. Then you can extend simplify to have `Sum(BoundValue(l), BoundValue(r)) => Const(l+r)` (etc). You can't easily just extend `eval` because it is just that, a (complete) evaluator. In other words, you can't fix this by just fiddling with the definition of `env`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a relatively clean solution. I've only included the pieces I modified.

```
type Environment = String => Option[Int]

lazy val env: Environment = {
  case "y" => Some(n2)
  case "z" => Some(n3)
  case _ => None
}

def simplify(t: Tree): Tree = {
  val reducedTree = t match {
    case Times(l, r)  => Times(simplify(l), simplify(r))
    case Sum(l, r)    => Sum(simplify(l), simplify(r))
    case Minus(l, r)  => Minus(simplify(l), simplify(r))
    case Divide(l, r) => Divide(simplify(l), simplify(r))
    case Var(n)       => env(n).map(Const).getOrElse(t)
    case _            => t
  }

  reducedTree match {
    case Times(Const(1), r)         => r
    case Times(l, Const(1))         => l
    case Times(Const(0), r)         => Const(0)
    case Times(l, Const(0))         => Const(0)
    case Times(Const(l), Const(r))  => Const(l * r)
    case Sum(Const(0), r)           => r
    case Sum(l, Const(0))           => l
    case Sum(Const(l), Const(r))    => Const(l + r)
    case Minus(l, Const(0))         => l
    case Minus(l, r) if l == r      => Const(0)
    case Minus(Const(l), Const(r))  => Const(l - r)
    case Divide(Const(0), r)        => Const(0)
    case Divide(l, Const(1))        => l
    case Divide(l, r) if l == r     => Const(1)
    case Divide(Const(l), Const(r)) => Const(l / r)
    case _                          => reducedTree
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a little bit to make it work as you want:

```
abstract class Tree
case class Sum(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree {
  override def toString = "(" + l + " + " + r + ")"
}
case class Minus(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree {
  override def toString = "(" + l + " - " + r + ")"
}
case class Times(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree {
  override def toString = "(" + l + " * " + r + ")"
}
case class Divide(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree {
  override def toString = "(" + l + " / " + r + ")"
}
case class Var(n: String) extends Tree {
  override def toString = n
}
case class Const(v: Int) extends Tree {
  override def toString = v.toString
}

object ExprEval {
  lazy val exp: Tree = Sum(Var("x"), Times(Var("x"), Minus(Var("y"), Divide(Var("z"), Const(2)))))
  var env = Map[String, Int]()

  def simplify(t: Tree, recursive : Boolean = true): Tree = {
    t match {
      case Sum(Const(0), r)           => simplify(r)
      case Sum(l, Const(0))           => simplify(l)
      case Sum(Const(l), Const(r))    => Const(l + r)
      case Sum(Var(l), Var(r)) if l == r => Times(Const(2), Var(l))
      case Sum(l, r) if recursive     => simplify(Sum(simplify(l), simplify(r)), recursive = false)

      case Minus(l, Const(0))         => simplify(l)
      case Minus(l, r) if l == r      => Const(0)
      case Minus(Const(l), Const(r))  => Const(l - r)
      case Minus(l, r) if recursive   => simplify(Minus(simplify(l), simplify(r)), recursive = false)

      case Times(Const(1), r)         => simplify(r)
      case Times(l, Const(1))         => simplify(l)
      case Times(Const(0), r)         => Const(0)
      case Times(l, Const(0))         => Const(0)
      case Times(Const(l), Const(r))  => Const(l * r)
      case Times(l, r) if recursive   => simplify(Times(simplify(l), simplify(r)), recursive = false)

      case Divide(Const(0), r)        => Const(0)
      case Divide(l, Const(1))        => simplify(l)
      case Divide(l, r) if l == r     => Const(1)
      case Divide(Const(l), Const(r)) => Const(l / r)
      case Divide(l, r) if recursive  => simplify(Divide(simplify(l), simplify(r)), recursive = false)

      case Var(n)                     => env.get(n).map(Const).getOrElse(Var(n))
      case _                          => t
    }
  }

  def eval(t: Tree): Int = t match {
    case Sum(l, r)    => eval(l) + eval(r)
    case Minus(l, r)  => eval(l) - eval(r)
    case Times(l, r)  => eval(l) * eval(r)
    case Divide(l, r) => eval(l) / eval(r)
    case Var(n)       => env(n)
    case Const(v)     => v
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    env = Map()
    println(s"env: $env, exp : $exp, simplified : ${simplify(exp)}")

    env = Map("y" -> 2, "z" -> 2)
    println(s"env: $env, exp : $exp, simplified : ${simplify(exp)}")

    env = Map("z" -> 4)
    println(s"env: $env, exp : $exp, simplified : ${simplify(exp)}")

    env = Map("x" -> 3, "y" -> 2, "z" -> 2)
    println(s"env: $env, exp : $exp, simplified : ${simplify(exp)}")
  }
}
```

If no variables are bound, it returns a simplified original expression tree. If all variables are bound, it produces the same result as eval().

Output:

```
env: Map(), exp : (x + (x * (y - (z / 2)))), simplified : (x + (x * (y - (z / 2))))
env: Map(y -> 2, z -> 2), exp : (x + (x * (y - (z / 2)))), simplified : (2 * x)
env: Map(z -> 4), exp : (x + (x * (y - (z / 2)))), simplified : (x + (x * (y - 2)))
env: Map(x -> 3, y -> 2, z -> 2), exp : (x + (x * (y - (z / 2)))), simplified : 6
```

Comment: One question, what is the purpose of checking recursive in those cases in the simplify method? I don't quite understand that

Comment: When simplify() can't make Sum/Minus/Times/Divide expression any simpler, it would select the least specific case handler for this operation and cause infinite recursion if there is no such check.